# Simplexml_load_file breaks if link comes from Drupals field_link

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, drupal, simplexml

I am trying to dynamically load a KML-File from Google Maps, that the user can configure over an input field in Drupal (Link field). However I am stuck, since the following works flawlessly, but the last one does not.

Works:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("Google Maps Link");
```

Works as well:

```
$link = "Google Maps Link";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);
```

Does not work:

```
$link = $fields['field_link']->content;
// produces "
//           http://www....."
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);
```

I don't really know what is going on here. I tried to use `trim()` or `htmlspecialchars()` (to see any weird char), but nothing worked so far. I only get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML()` on a non-object but this is just due to the fact that the xml does not get loaded. `simplexml_load_file` returns false. When I print the two links, then they are identical. The only thing I see is that the link from Drupal has some char at the beginning that forces it into a new line. Don't know how to identify it though.

Comment: what does `print_r($fields['field_link']->content)` produce?

Comment: something like "(some break) MY-LINK (in new line)". See above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove unidentified (and unspecified) whitespace from your link using `preg_replace` and `\s`, which represents any whitespace character:

```
$link = '
            http://www.example.com';

$link = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $link);
echo ">" . $link . "<" . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
>http://www.example.com<
```

You should now be able to load it using `simplexml_load_file($link);`.

Comment: Hey, while I am agree that this is the right solution (especially since it actually removed the space), I decided to use the hardcoded link, since it still would not work.